# In Adwords is it possible show ads during particular times for multiple time zones

Tags: google-ads

Is it possible to have a campaign covering lots of countries / lots of different time zones, and to have ads showing only during particular times of day as per those time zones -- for example between 9a and 5p for each time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that [this is possible](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=27470&guide=27459&page=guide.cs):

> #### Ad Scheduling
>
> Ad Scheduling (also known as "day parting") lets you tell Google exactly when you want your ads to run, and more importantly, when you do not want them to run. In addition, more advanced users can automatically modify their bids based on time-of-day and day-of-week cycles in campaign performance.
>
> Ad Scheduling can help you with improving ROI for your display campaigns by ensuring that your ads show at times where it performs the best. For example, if you notice that you are getting the most conversions from Monday to Friday and nothing on Saturday and Sunday, you can schedule your ads to appear only during those times so that you are maximizing your ad's performance with your given budget.

It also says "You can set an ad schedule for particular hours of the day, or specific days of the week", so this looks like what you want. Still might be a fair bit of work to set up, of course...

Comment: This takes a few seconds to set up. But I need this to apply to timezones. I'm in the GMT timezone, so if I set times, do they apply to my timezone only? If I set 9am to 5pm as the times my ads show, do they show at 9am to 5pm in the timezone GMT-7 or do they show in the GMT-7 timezone at 9am to 5pm as per GMT time?

Comment: I suspect you would have to ask on the Google Adwords support forums to find that out (or try it and see what happens).. but if you do, can you come back and edit this answer to let us know?

Comment: it looks like the time setting applies to my timezone only. as far as i can gather i don't think there's a way to deal with showing ads at different times of days for multiple timezones in one campaign, other than adding countries in and taking them back out again at different times of day